SwiftUI No ContextMenu on Recursive List
I am trying to port a program written in Java to SwiftUI. The basic structure of the UI is a navigation tree on the left side of the main view. The user might select one item and the several details will be displayed in tables on the right.
The nodes in the navigation tree allow different actions - depending on their type.
These actions should be implemented as context menus.

I have implemented a small example, but I could not get the context menu to work.
I guess that I am using a wrong approach. Here is my example code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  @State var selection = Set<Tree<String>>()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List(treeNodes, id: \.value, children: \.children, selection: $selection) { tree in
        NavigationLink {
          TabView {
            Tab("Details 1", image: "Block") {
              Text(tree.value)
            }
            Tab("Details 2", image: "Haus") {
              Text(tree.value)
            }
          }
        } label: {
          Label(tree.value, image: tree.icon!)
        }
      }
      .contextMenu(forSelectionType: Tree<String>.self) { nodes in
         if nodes.count == 1 {
          Button("One node selected") {}
        } else {
          Button("No node or more than 1 selected") {}
        }
      }
      .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}

For completing the code
import SwiftUI

// MARK: - Tree
/// Class for arbitrary trees. Values must be hashable
class Tree<Value: Hashable>: Hashable {

  var value: Value
  var icon: String?
  var children: [Tree]?

  init(value: any Hashable, icon: String? = nil, children: [Tree]? = nil) {
    // swiftlint: disable force_cast
    self.value = value as! Value
    // swiftlint: enable force_cast
    self.icon = icon
    self.children = children
  }

  static func == (lhs: Tree<Value>, rhs: Tree<Value>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
  }

  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(value)
  }
}

// MARK: - Value
/// Class for the stored value
class Value: Hashable, Equatable {
  var id = UUID()

  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
  }

  static func == (lhs: Value, rhs: Value) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
  }
}

// MARK: - init demo data
/// example data using string values
let treeNodes: [Tree<String>] = [
  .init(
    value: "Root", icon: "Block",
    children: [
      .init(value: "House 1", icon: "Haus"),
      .init(value: "House 2", icon: "Haus"),
      .init(
        value: "House 3", icon: "Haus",
        children: [
          .init(value: "Apartment 1", icon: "Wohnung"),
          .init(value: "Apartment 2", icon: "Wohnung")
        ]
      )
    ]
  )
]


You should look at some basic SwiftUI tutorials. SwiftUI is very different from Java. There is so much “wrong” here that you have an uphill battle ahead

You should not mix the new APIs with the old APIs. Use a NavigationSplitView instead of a NavigationView. After that, the code works as expected.
NavigationSplitView {
    List(treeNodes, id: \.value, children: \.children, selection: $selection) { tree in
        NavigationLink(value: tree) {
            // why make icon optional when you are going to force unwrap it?
            Label(tree.value, image: tree.icon!)
        }
    }
    .contextMenu(forSelectionType: Tree<String>.self) { nodes in
        if nodes.count == 1 {
            Button("One node selected") {}
        } else {
            Button("No node or more than 1 selected") {}
        }
    }
    .listStyle(.sidebar)
} detail: {
    // I'm not sure if TabViews in a detail view is officially supported.
    // consider using a segmented Picker to act as tabs instead.
    TabView {
        // it is unclear what detail view you want to show when multiple items are selected, 
        // so here I have just used a random one from the set
        if let tab = selection.first {
            Tab("Details 1", image: "Block") {
                Text(tab.value)
            }
            Tab("Details 2", image: "Haus") {
                Text(tab.value)
            }
        } else {
            Tab {
                Text("No selection")
            }
        }
    }
}

Also consider changing Tree to a struct, as they are much easier to work with in SwiftUI. You just need:
struct Tree<Value: Hashable>: Hashable {
    var value: Value
    var icon: String?
    var children: [Tree]?
}

If you really want Tree to be a class, you should make it @Observable, or else SwiftUI will not be able to see changes in value, icon, children in order to update the view.
I'm not sure what the Value class is trying to accomplish.

Thanks for the corrections. My problem is almost solved. What I really want to do is, that I want to display different context menus, depending on the type of node selected.  For example if a node is a directory or file.

@hjbflyer What is the "type" of a node? Is that the value string? So just change if nodes.count == 1 to check for value instead.

@hjbflyer For directory vs file, I assume it will could be encoded as whether children is nil? So just check for that instead.

Thank you. My nodes are a litte bit more complicated - I did prepare a small example. In real I do have 4 different object types in the navigation view. These objects are referenced in the Tree.  So now I will check  refObject  == isKindOfClass(...)

@hjbflyer Okay. What is problematic about it? In any case, this sounds like another whole can of worms. If you have further questions about this, I'd suggest posting a new question, and include a representative example of your real code. 4 classes sounds like it'd be very hard to work with in SwiftUI - I would suggest using an enum with 4 cases, each with their own associated values. Are you translating your Java code word-by-word to Swift? I strongly recommend you not to do that. Rethink the problem in Swift.

Many thanks for your suggestions. I will rethink my problem.   Basically I do have different hierarchical objects in the tree  and several tabs with tables showing detail aspects of the selected object.
